# ASP.NET MVC - How to use custom Culture in EvoHtmlToPdf

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf

my program (ASP.NET MVC with VB.NET) is to convert local HTML(with dynamic conrtoller action) to PDF file using third-party tools (EvoHtmlToPdf)

However, my local HTML contains a lot of CSS and I can only use EvoHtmlToPdf's API to convert PDF (pass the link to the function)

```
outPdfBuffer = htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertUrl(Me.Url.Action("TestDownloadPDFText", "ReportA", New With {.Culture = Session("Culture")}, Me.Request.Url.Scheme))
```

Whatever I set the culture in different place, the PDF will be showed in English only. If I just try http://localhost/ReportA/TestDownloadPDFText and it can show Chinese when I hard code Chinese culture in code behind.

So, I guess the problem is coming from the third-party tools (EvoHtmlToPdf). Any suggestion or solution for this case? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem. The solution is to add culture configuration in that controller.

```
Dim ci As CultureInfo
ci = New CultureInfo(Culture)
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name)
```

Thanks all.